# Readable set of constant parameters C

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, struct, constants

I'd like to create a more readable and usable for other programmers to read and modify my code.
I have some sets of identical constants type which i want to only read in my code.

I tried using an array of structures as follow (the idea is to create a sort of template in which i can easily put manually new sets of parameter):

Then initialize them somewhere in my code.
But i think, being my target to have a cleaner code, this way is not so cleaner in the end.

Advice?
Best Regards,

Davide

```
typedef struct  
{
    const char      Name[30];
    const char      OptionValName[255][20];
    const uint8_t   Default;
    const uint8_t   UpLimit;
    const char      ErrorString[30];
    const uint8_t   MenuType ;
    const uint8_t   ButtonType;
    const uint8_t   ButtPosition;
    const uint8_t   PagePosition;   
    
}Parameter_St;

Parameter_St Parameter[10];
```

Comment: I do see the idea of the struct. Please explain the idea of the array.

Comment: Declaring any, much less all, of a struct's members to be `const` typically makes the struct difficult to work with.  Among other things, no, you *cannot* "initialize them somewhere in your code".  `const` objects cannot be modified.  They take their values when they are first allocated, possibly from an initializer in their delcaration.

Answer (score 0):

suggest a 'config' file that contains all the constant data.

Then the actual code opens that 'config' file, reading the data and using that data to set the values in the array of structs.